# Base64 img not showing after Winnovative PDFConverter HTML to PDF

Tags: image, base64, html-to-pdf, winnovative

I’ve been using the PDFConverter for years with no issues. And there are still no issues converting a large HTML form to PDF, except certain images aren’t showing.

I programmatically fill an HTML img element with a base64 string, like so:

imgSignature.Src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(SignatureImage);

where SignatureImage is a byte[] array.

I've observed that if the byte[] array size is more than around 7K (not sure exactly the threshold), the image will not render to PDF (at least it’s not visible anyway). Anything under that displays fine. Note: the image displays in HTML just fine. It's when converting to PDF that it disappears if the byte array is too large

I've tried adjust the size of the img, the container it's in, everything I can think of.

Currently still going through Winnovative support docs but no luck so far.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Have you tried setting `ConversionDelay`?

Comment: "Have you tried setting ConversionDelay? – OutstandingBill"

No, I had not tried that. Unfortunately it did not help, but thanks for the suggestion. It may help others.

Comment: Did you get this working? I am about to start creating a report where I planned on relying on using images as base64 strings. Which version of Winnovative are you using? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just in my case, I changed all images formats from jpeg to png, and it works for me. It's worth mentioning that my images are between 6kb to 8 kb (the images are Bar Codes)